# Не отображается редакция

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, правки, ревизии

Есть [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474386/324730) ответ и его [редакции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/474386/revisions). Почему-то не отображается 24-ая редакция.

[image]

Описана как "Добавлена ссылка, удалено 136 символов", но не видно никаких изменений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю в какой версии, но баг уже исправили.
Прошу поставить [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be).

Answer (score 0):

Переключи в режим разметки:

UPDATE: И обнови страницу... Действительно что-то она глючит...

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вот ["Внутристроченный"](https://imgur.com/TK2ht3V.png), ["В две колонки"](https://imgur.com/vzbMTdE.png) и ["В две колонки с Markdown"](https://imgur.com/1QXQSc9.png) - не отображается нигде. Думаю проблема только у меня.

Comment: Да, после обновления появляется. Но теперь переключился на "В две колонки" и уже не могу переключаться ни на что другое, даже при обновлении страницы.

Comment: @eccs0103, нажми на соседней версии, потом обнови страницу.

Comment: Если переключиться с «В две колонки с Markdown» на «Внутристрочно», то страница начинает бесконечно флудить ajax-запросами